# Jquery autocomplete click outside bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm facing the following issue with Jquery autocomplete:
- I'm trying (and manage) to clear text field if nothing is selected, but if user click outside without selecting anything and then perform the same request again nothing happens

- You can try it yourself: (a fiddle that is not mine but bugging the same way)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcHgY/

- try to type "per" for instance then click outside, and type again "per". autocomplete won't work until you make change to the request.

here is the code:

```
$(function () {
 $("#tags").autocomplete({
     source: availableTags,
     close:function(){
         this.value=''
     },
     select:function(e,ui){
         /* do something with selected result*/
         $('body').append('<div>You Chose '+ui.item.value+'</div>');

     }
 });
```

});

Any ideas are welcome!
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Setting the delay in the options will eliminate this "bug," for example to 0 or 100 (0 not recommended for remote data as it can put excess load on your server but fine for a local array like in the example):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcHgY/22/

```
$(function () {
 $("#tags").autocomplete({
     source: availableTags,
     delay: 100,
     close:function(){
         this.value=''
     },
     select:function(e,ui){
         /* do something with selected result*/
         $('body').append('<div>You Chose '+ui.item.value+'</div>');

   }
 });
```

Comment: I've tried and this is solving the issue. But only if the user type slowly enough. Even with delay set to 100 (instead of 300 by default) with keypad typing the problem can occur. Isn't there a bulletproof way that can reset properly the input and allow longer delay? (on new search you can type as fast you want).